# Polymer customelements's content get inserted below the element?

Tags: html, polymer

I have a bunch of custom elements in the Polymer project (probably too many, but that's something I'm working one.)

My problem is, the content of these `<gb-course>`'s seems to be being inserted *below* the `<gb-course>` itself, and I cannot figure out why.

(If you notice those little black bars above the first bold word in the center column, that's supposed to be a 1px border-bottom on the `<gb-course>` itself. Which it is, according to Chrome/Firefox/Safari, but why is the content being stuck under the element?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Without knowing how you've created these elements, it's hard to say what's going on. My guess is that you need to put a style tag in the gb-course that sets `:host {display: block;}`. Custom elements are display inline by default.

Comment: Damn. That worked. Thanks! (If you want to post that as a solution, I'll gladly accept it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need to put a style tag in the gb-course that sets `:host {display: block;}`. Custom elements are display: inline by default.